# 2D Shadow Effect - Points on circle

Tags: python, geometry, 2d, trigonometry, shadows

I am currently trying to implement flat shadow effects to a 2D game that i have written in Python. I have found a great deal of tutorials and methods of doing this online (http://ncase.me/sight-and-light/) however, these all use polygons as the obstructions, where all corner points are known while my game includes circles.

[image]

I was wondering if it were possible to calculate either the X and Y coordinates of each of the points of contact (P and Q) or the gradient of the line if the situation of A and O and the radius of the circle are known.

Thanks in advance and apologies if the question is off topic, but i couldn't find the answers anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to notice what is happening at point P.  At point P, the line AP is tangent to the circle so in other words the angle APO is 90 degrees.  Likewise AQO is 90 degrees.

Now we know that we have a triangle, we know 2 of the lengths and one of the angles (We know AO, OP / OQ (Same thing), and APO / AQO).

We now use the law of sines.

```
 AO/sin(APO) = OP/sin(PAO)
 PAO = asin(OP*(sin(APO)/AO))
```

Remember to be conscious of the units (ie using 90 degrees as an input value and then forgetting that a your library function for sin may return in radians not degrees).

From here, you can find all of the angles by knowing that the sum of all angles in a triangle is 180 degrees.  So now you have all three angles.

When you have angle AOP from the above calculation, you can use the law of sines again to calculate the length of AP.

```
 AP = sin(AOP) * AO / sin(APO).
```

Note that sin(90 degrees) == 1 (And remember that APO and AQO are 90 degrees | pi/2 radians).

Now we have the length of AP.  We can now find the coordinates (x, y) of P, assuming that A is at (0, 0).  If A is not the origin just add A's coordinates as an offset.

To find the coordinates of P:

```
 PxCoord = AxCoord + AP * cos(PAO)
 PyCoord = AyCoord + AP * sin(PAO)
```

**Reminder: Please check if your trig functions (sin / asin) use degrees or radians, and make sure to convert the 90 degrees to radians (it is pi/2 radians) if your function uses radians.  Also note that if this is the case, your output will be in radians for the angle, and likewise instead of there being 180 degrees in a triangle you will have pi radians.**

Answer (score 1):

Let's vector V = OP (unknown), vector Q = AP, vector U = AO (known)
Note that Q = U + V

Vector V length is radius R, so

```
VX^2 + VY^2 = R^2   //1
```

Vectors V and A are perpendicular, so their scalar product is zero

```
VX * QX + VY * QY = 0
VX * (VX + UX) + VY * (VY  + UY) = 0
VX * VX + VX * UX + VY * VY  + VY * UY = 0
R^2 + VX * UX + VY * UY = 0   //2
```

Solve system of equations 1 and 2 and get solutions

```
LL = U.X^2 + U.Y^2

VY = (R^2 * UY  +/- R * UX * Sqrt(LL - R^2)) / LL
VX = (R^2 - VY * UY) / UX
```

and finally

```
P.X = O.X + VX
P.Y = O.Y + VY
```